# Shifting as data augmentation in Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I have few images with that I want data augmentation for CNN (convolution neural network) training.

As I know some of the operations for data augmentation are:
**rotation, vertical and horizontal flipping, shifting(position of object)** and many more.

But my doubt is whether **shifting** of the object in the image really matters in CNN. If it does, then how does it matter.

Answer (score 1):

If all the objects are centered, then there is no problem. But if the objects can be in different parts of the image, then shifting could be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for answering, actually prediction time, the object will be in the center and for training, I have the images in the center only. Will shifting be relevant to in this case??

Comment: And one last question, as I mentioned in the question `if it does, then how does it matter.`?? Please answer this also. This is about general case where the data is not in the center.

Comment: If the images in train data and in data for prediction will be centered, you won't need to apply shift. Let's imagine that you have 4 images - in all of them the objects are in different corners.
Technically these images will be different for CNN. Weights create "a mask" which shows what is the important object in the image. And if the object is in different parts of images the mask will change from image to image.